# Powershell script to delete files older than x days, but not folders

Tags: powershell

I have a script that I thought was working, but I'm getting reports that its deleting folders instead of just files. Can someone help me adjust my script to account for this? Do I need to add a -file filter?

```bash
$Path = "D:\AppData\Downloads"

$Limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)

Get-ChildItem -path $Path -Recurse -force | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $Limit } | Remove-Item -recurse -Force
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Where-Object clause is most likely not working like you expect it to.

```
{!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $Limit }
```

Should be

```
{!$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.CreationTime -lt $Limit)}
```

The brackets ensure the second logical comparison is evaluated independantly. See  about_logical_operators for more information

> The Windows PowerShell logical operators evaluate only the statements 
>       required to determine the truth value of the statement. If the left operand
>       in a statement that contains the and operator is FALSE, the right operand
>       is not evaluated. If the left operand in a statement that contains 
>       the or statement is TRUE, the right operand is not evaluated. As a result,
>       you can use these statements in the same way that you would use 
>       the If statement.

Also since it is removing files and not folders the `-Recurse` for `Remove-Item` seems unnecessary. 
From the comment by Alroc: Assuming you have version 3 or above of PowerShell you can simplify this by using the `-File` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` in place of the `!$_.PSIsContainer` clause of your `Where-Object` (which is what was commonly done in Version 2.) Just like you have in your comment:

```
Get-ChildItem -path $Path -file -Recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $Limit }
```

Comment: In v3 and later, you can use the `-file` switch for `get-childitem` and skip inspecting `$_.PSIsContainer` on each object in the `where-object`.

Comment: Thanks Matt and alroc. So does this look better? 

Get-ChildItem -path $Path -file -Recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $Limit } | Remove-Item -Force

Comment: @Powershell_Toddler it _looks_ fine but you should test it first. Just remove the `Remove-Item` in testing and check what your results are. Good work!

Comment: -whatif is showing only files, and after removing -whatif I still have folders with last modified dates older than 6 days. Looks like its working, thanks for the help!